# How to convert date in this format 'Dec-07-2013 09:32:05 CST' in GWT

Tags: date, gwt

In GWT Whats the correct format to convert date something like

Dec-07-2013 09:32:05 CST

Im using "mmm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" but getting UTC -5 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Is UTC -5 not equal to CST (during Dayligh tSaving Time)?

http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=6,100&h=6